# Как работает WebPack

Tags: javascript, webpack

У меня есть проект и в нём куча подключённых библиотек, например `lodash`. Из этой библиотеки я использую пока только одну функцию `_.isEqual`, я хочу понять после обработки webpack-ом моего проекта, в результирующий JavaScript попадут все функции `lodash` или только `isEqual`?

Аналогично и с css неиспользованые селекторы попадают в результат?

Конечно я могу создать простой проект и проверить, так сказать на практике, но хочется узнать как вообще это должно работать.

Comment: Если вы просто подключаете библиотеку/обрабатываете препроцессором стили, то все будет в полном объеме. Есть плагины скажем для реакта, где стили будут подключаться только используемые, есть способы выдергивать из js библиотек только нужные методы, но это явно не ваш вариант.

Comment: @MedvedevDev вот так я и подозревал... а что ему мешает сразу лишнее не включать, это же логично...

Comment: @MedvedevDev у меня React проект и в Webpack конфиге указано что точка начала сборки это boot файл react проекта. Я подумал что он проанализирует дерево включений, и включит только то что нужно. Но что-то подозрительно большим получается выходной файл, отсюда и возник вопрос.

Comment: Вебпак "из коробки" это просто сборщик со своими инструкциями, дальше уже все зависит от подключаемых пакетов.

Comment: @MedvedevDev то есть нужен какой-то специальный пакет что бы он не включал то что не используется?

Comment: Ну, как-то так и есть ... Скажем для стилей можно использовать [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader)

Comment: @MedvedevDev а для javascript-а нету плагина?

Comment: Зависит от библиотек ... для лодаша вроде как [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin) есть

Comment: @MedvedevDev что-то я не понимаю, а что сложно пройти по всем функциям и просто не включать те которые не используются, почему нету коробочного и универсального способа. Вот смотрите. В каждой функции пройдясь по её коду мы знаем какие функции мы вызываем из неё. Исходя из исходного файла мы можем получить дерево, список всех используемых функций, а остальное просто не включать в результат... или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: @MedvedevDev почитав в интернете я нашёл что есть такая штука Tree shaking это мне и нужно, но есть ли это в Webзack неизвестно, но это точно есть в rollup. Так что буду по нему читать документацию, и возможно буду на него переходить. https://rollupjs.org

Comment: Приветствую! Тут дело не столько в вебпаке/роллап, так как вебпак со второй версии поддерживает es6 тришейкинг. А дело в том, как модули импортировать. У вас разве не на тайпсприпте проект, или это другой? Потому что тайпскрипт чуть меняет ситуацию (т.к. бабель плагины не используются).

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ и добавил вариант №3 typescript+babel вместе. Так получилось, что я как раз сейчас настраиваю этот вариант у себя, так как замучался без некоторых плагинов бабеля. Надеюсь будет интересно или полезно. Удачи!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приветствую!

Тут дело не столько в вебпаке/роллап, так как вебпак со второй версии поддерживает es6 тришейкинг. А дело в том, как модули импортировать. У вас разве не на тайпсприпте проект, или это другой? Потому что тайпскрипт чуть меняет ситуацию (т.к. бабель плагины не используются).

**Подробности:**

Дело в том, что если в бандлер (после всех прелоадеров) попадёт es5-код вида (наверное правильнее сказать, что это commonjs модули)

```
var lodash_1 = require('lodash');
var map = lodash_1.map;
```

Тогда +700 килобайт к размеру бандла обеспечено. Так как бандлер не будет знать, как этот объект `lodash_1` уменьшить.

Если же в бандлер попадает es6 импорт типа

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
```

Тогда умный бандлер дёрнет из библиотеки только то, что мы используем.

---

**Далее встаёт вопрос - как же не допустить попадания подобного кода в бандлер? Вариантов несколько**

**1)** В чистом js можно, в общем-то, использоваться бабель-плагин-лодаш, он кстати не только с лодашем работает, а также, к примеру, с semantic-ui-react.

**2)** Можно испортировать функции по одной
const map = require('lodash/map');

**3)** Можно устанавливать только те функции лодаш из npm, которые нужны (но это если нужно всего несколько)

```
npm install lodash.map
npm install lodash.sortBy
```

---

В тайпкрипте, ситуация чуть другая и зависит от параметра `target` в tsconfig.

**1)** Если параметр равен es5, тогда тришейкинг работать не будет, так как мы передаём ес5 код в бандлер. В этом случае можно и нужно импортировать функции по одной:

import map = require('lodash/map');

Как вариант, можно создать файл, который будет импортировать нужные функции по одной, и реэкспортировать все вместе, вот так:

```
// utils/lodash.ts
import clamp = require('lodash/clamp');
import curry = require('lodash/curry');
import debounce = require('lodash/debounce');
import filter = require('lodash/filter');

export { clamp, curry, debounce, filter };
```

**2)** Если target = es6 и выше, тогда в бандлер приходит es6 код и всё должно быть хорошо.

---

**3)** Ещё вариант - typescript + babel.

```
// webpack.config.js
{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                  compilerOptions: {
                    jsx: 'preserve',
                    target: 'es2015',
                    module: 'es2015'
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            include: SRC_ROOT
}

// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Возможно, самый гибкий вариант, так как позволяет использовать все доступные бабель-плагины, в том числе те, которым нет альтернативы (к примеру, плагин для дебага styled-components).

Важно убедиться, что в тайпскрипте target = es6 или выше. Таким образом вся нагрузка по переводу в ес5 ложиться на бабель.

В данном случае можно использовать бабель-лодаш-плагин и другие.

---

1) В вебпаке есть очень хорошие плагины - инструменты профилирования сборки.
Один из низ - WebpackMonitor, что это такое можно погуглить, **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЕН при продакшн-сборке**:

```
new WebpackMonitor({
  capture: true, // -> default 'true'
  launch: false, // -> default 'false'
  port: 3030, // default -> 8081
  target: 'stats.prod.json'
}),
```

Он показывает из чего состоит бандл, сколько это весит, а также хранит историю изменений.

2) Обязательно стоит завести 2 конфига для вебпака. Точнее 3:

```
webpack.common.js
webpack.dev.js
webpack.production.js
```

В common настраиваем общие параметры. В дев и прод. импортирует общий конфиг и дополняем требуемыми настройками/плагинами/лоадерами. К примеру, WebpackMonitor идёт в продакшн. ExtractText тоже в продакшн. И т.д.